# What is "DOMException: Entry already exists"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb, service-worker, domexception

tl;dr My web app is getting the error "DOMException: Entry already exists" and I have no idea what it means.  I haven't been able to find an explanation for this error on the internet; possibly my googlefoo is inadequate.

---

Longer version.

I have fairly straightforward todolist es6 app that

- stores stuff locally in IndexedDB and
- uses a service worker to intercept a fetch to "/sync" to run some code which syncs the IndexedDB with a server.
- uses a service worker to cache the main page (using [cache.put](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/put), which shouldn't complain if the cache entry already exists)

Everything works great.  But every once and awhile, the service worker gives off the errors...

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: network error at TypeError (native) (program:1)
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Entry already exists. (program:1)
```

...chrome (45.0.2454.93 (64-bit) on ubuntu) slows to a crawl, and nothing works until I go to chrome://serviceworker-internals and stop the service worker.  After that everything is fine for another couple days.

Hard to debug since the error doesn't tell me what line of my code initiated the problem.

Comment: You should be able to at least expand a stack trace in the console, I'd expect. Do you have any idea what code triggers this?

Comment: I'm afraid "program:1" *is* the stack trace.  So no I have no idea where this is coming from.  Weird, right?

Comment: That's what it says in the right side of the console, but there should be an arrow to the left of "Uncaught" that will expand the actual error object with an stack trace.

Comment: You should be able to overwrite an existing cache entry with a new `Response` without issues. Poking around a bit leads to https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=510002#c10 which makes me think that exception is an internal Chrome error rather than a problem with your code. I'd recommend filing an issue at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list, ideally with a copy of your code + a live site where it can be reproduced.

Comment: Yeah there's no arrow for a more detailed stack trace.  (program):1 is all it has to say.   Well, I guess I'll try getting rid of functionality until the bug goes away, and then maybe I can isolate the thing... thanks!

Comment: +1 to Jeff Posnick's reference to https://crbug.com/510002 - a DOMException with name "InternalAccessError" and message "Entry already exists" should NOT (per spec) be generated by the Cache API, but there's a Chrome bug in the cache backing store causing it with some frequency, specifically on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, but to answer more definitively:

This was tracked down to a Windows-specific bug in the Cache API implementation in Chrome - https://crbug.com/542668

A fix is in progress, with code going in. The fix should wind its way through the normal Chrome release process - Canary build within a day or two, Beta in a few weeks, and Stable release ~6 weeks after that.